Linux - почему visudo: /etc/sudoers: Operation not permitted?
Мне нужно дать возможность пользователю telegraf запускать fail2ban от sudo без пароля
Вот тут приведен пример
Я делаю это через visudo, напрямую вроде как их не рекомендуют редактировать файлы пользователя в /etc/sudoers.d/ , чтобы не сломать sudo.
sudo su -
[sudo] password for user1:
root@host1:~# whoami
root
root@host1:~# groups
root
root@host1:~# id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
root@host1:~# visudo
visudo: /etc/sudoers: Operation not permitted

root@host1:~# ls -la /etc/sudoers.d/
drwxr-x---   2 root root  4096 Dec 20  2023 .
drwxr-xr-x 138 root root 12288 Nov 27 11:49 ..
-r--r-----   1 root root   106 Mar 10  2022 telegraf


права файла -r--r----- означает, что вы можете его открывать только для чтения. поменяете права chmod и добавьте возможность модификации. -rw-r-----

А можно на эти файлы ставить такие? Я думал что так сделано , чтобы только visudo могла корректно с ними работать

@AlexGlebe для sudoers так делать не надо

Вам нужно использовать именно команду sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/telegraf, не просто sudo visudo, как указано в документации.
